# How do I test that a function is called within a method using jest+enzyme+react+typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enzyme, jestjs

Say I have this method in my react component

```
handleSubmit(){
    if (this.state.fireRedirect === false){
        this.setState({ fireRedirect: true }, () => { this.addEndpoint() });
    }
}
```

How do I test that addEndpoint was called using Jest and Enzyme?

Comment: does this `addEndpoint` method leaves any checkable trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [jest.spyOn](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestspyonobject-methodname)

```
  const spy = jest.spyOn(Component.prototype, "addEndPoint");
  const wrapper = shallow(<Component/>);
  expect(spy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  wrapper.instance().handleSubmit();
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```